# VBScript Error when calling GetObject("WinNT://JohnDoe,User")

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, activex, adsi

I have code that hasn't been touched in over a year, but the DCs were upgraded from 2008 to 2008 R2. The AD folks claim it’s not the DC upgrade but the issue started promptly after that went in.

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'
>   Permission denied: 'GetObject'

It's failing on the Set Group line.

```
Set Group = GetObject("WinNT://" & Logon_name & ",User")

For each Member in Group.Groups
  If Member.Class = "Group" then
    If Member.Name = "TEST_AD_GROUP" Or Member.Name = "TEST_AD_GROUP2" then
      x = "true"
      Exit For
    End If
  End If
Next
```

Thanks.

Comment: In which user account context does the script execute? Maybe it's locked-out on the domain level (but cached on the machine it executes on)?

Comment: it should be running as the COMPUTER account.

Comment: "Should"? Can you check? Chances are that it really is a genuine "access denied" message.

Comment: it is running under the computer account.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i had to change the code to pass in the userid and pwd.

```
Set objIADS = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & strDomain, strUsername, strPassword, ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
Set objIADSUser = objIADS.GetObject("user", strUsername)

For each Member in objIADSUser.Groups
    If Member.Class = "Group" then
        If Member.Name = "TEST_AD_GROUP" then
            x = "true"
            EXIT FOR
        End If
    End If
Next
```